# Visual Studio 22 Remote Manager tries to connect to a WSL system instead of a real remote server

Tags: visual-studio-2022

some time ago I used several WSL "containers" on my Windows 11 system, and connected to them via Visual Studio to compile & debug remotely.

To do this, I actually created an ssh server on the WSL instance and then connected to ssh via the local host.

Meanwhile, I have an Ubuntu 22 server that physically exists.
I have Visual Studio Code set up with the remote extension and an ssh key so that I can compile/debug ect. directly on the remote system.

I would like to do the same under Visual Studio 22 Community Edition.

But here I run into a problem which makes me think that Visual Studio is trying to connect to a remote ssh of a WSL system:

Here I used the private key which I also used over various other ssh clients and vs code.
This key does not contain a passphrase.

[image: Remote Manager failed to add a connection]

[image: error log]

What irritates me very much are all the liblinux. outputs.
I have already deleted WSL and all containers from my system.
The VS22 settings I have also already completely deleted.
I have also uninstalled VS 22 completely and reinstalled it.

Does anyone else have any ideas?